# Error en mysql variable es embigua

Tags: php, mysql

tengo la siguiente consulta en mysql:

Le estoy diciendo que seleccione dos tablas (demoras,trabajos) y que me sume la columna hora.

El problema es que la columna hora se repite también en la tabla trabajos.

```
$sql = ("SELECT demorat, hora, minuto, refe, reporte, id_trabajo, equipo, flota, SUM(hora) AS hours, SUM(minuto) AS minute 
FROM demoras,trabajos WHERE trabajos.reporte_kal BETWEEN '$fecha_md' AND '$fecha_md1'
AND trabajos.refe=demoras.refe group by demoras.demorat");
```

Como podría hacer para que solo me sume la columna hora de la tabla demoras?

Ya que actualmente me dice que esa columna es ambigua, osea que se repite en ambas tablas.

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar me seria de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: Simplemente cada vez que invoques a la columna hora precedela de la tabla a la que pertenece así `tabla.columna` así sabrá a cual haces referencia

Comment: Deberías ser riguroso en tu código y, cada vez que escribas consultas con más de una tabla, preceder cada columna con el nombre real o alias de su tabla correspondiente, así evitarás errores de este tipo y sabrás siempre con qué tablas/columnas estás trabajando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En sql puedes usar un "alias" o usar el nombre de las tablas y de esta forma resolver la ambiguedad.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT t1.horas, sum(t2.horas)
FROM demoras t1, trabajos t2

SELECT demoras.horas, sum(trabajos.horas)
FROM demoras, trabajos
```

Ambas formas son equivalentes, y así rompes la ambiguedad

Comment: Tu repuesta me fue de gran ayuda, muchas gracias.